# Angular6 and Bootstrap4 collapsible div does not work

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular6

There is accordion control provided with bootstrap4 https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#accordion-example

When I try to use this with my angular 6 app , it does not collapse. There is no error in the browser but it does not work. Any idea on this one ?

```html
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is live code example
https://stackblitz.com/github/Rugved/ng6bt4Demo/
jquery included in angular.json file

```json
"styles": [
  "src/styles.css",
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
],
"scripts": [
  "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",    
  "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"                        
]
```

Comment: Sorry can you explain further ? This is just bootstrap code, there is no api call to observe.

Comment: sorry!! deleted earlier comment. I was for other question

Comment: can you please check whether you have included bootstrap dependency in package.json?

Comment: yes , if you check the link, you can see that the bootstrap styles are applied

Comment: as mentioned by @SubSUl please include jQuery

Comment: yes jquery is included

Comment: To use jquery inside angular is not a good practice. many angular module available to archive this with out jquery. Try this one https://mdbootstrap.com/angular/advanced/collapse/

Comment: @Zeus your code works perfectly fine for me. Not having any problem.

Comment: I don't think you need to include `"node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",` in `angular.json` file. `bootstrap.js` already includes popper.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code works perfectly fine for me.

Please find the below configurations

**package.json**

```
{
"bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
"popper.js": "^1.14.3",
"jquery": "3.3.1"
}
```

**angular.json**

```
"styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ]
```

Comment: Thanks Pratap  but I do have that in my package. Order was different so I updated as yours but still  not working. Does it work for you ? any chance of uploading your demo ?

Comment: I had to rebuild the project, it works now. I was missing jquery and I think order was not right

Answer (score 1):

You need to include `jQuery` for many of the components in bootstrap to function.

Checkout this [pen](https://codepen.io/SubSul/pen/dqqraL), if you comment jQuery, collpase does not work, when you uncomment it works.

From bootstrap [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/#js)

> Many of our components require the use of JavaScript to function.
>   Specifically, they require jQuery, Popper.js, and our own JavaScript
>   plugins. Place the following s near the end of your pages,
>   right before the closing  tag, to enable them. jQuery must come
>   first, then Popper.js, and then our JavaScript plugins.

The bootstrap package you've included does not contain jQuery. From [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap#whats-included),

> Bundled JS files (bootstrap.bundle.js and minified bootstrap.bundle.min.js)
>   include Popper, but not jQuery.

Comment: Hi good points, I do have jquery included in package.json file. Still no effect